# How to decrement a value in an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, console, console-application, decrement

Assuming there's a three heart stored in an array.

string lives = new string [3] {"<3", "<3", "<3"};

This is intended for a quiz game. How do I remove a value from the lives array whenever the user inputs wrong answers?

For ex:
Lives is <3<3<3, but since the user input is wrong, lives became <3<3.

I'm expecting a for loop and decrement for this. I'm very puzzled as I am still new to for loops.

A new solution or help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Use a List<string>.  Much easier to manipulate the contents.

Comment: Why isn't the value for "lives" simply stored as an integer?  You can render "hearts" to the output based on that integer.  But the data itself is just the number `3` here.  Which you'd decrement to `2` by subtracting `1` from it.

Comment: If you are intent on using an array of strings, you could utilize `Linq` and do something like the following: `lives = lives.Length > 1 ? lives.Take(lives.Length - 1).ToArray() : new string[0];`

Comment: you should definitly separata your **data** (=number of lives) from its **represenation** (the heart-symbol). Then it's pretty simple to add or remove lives and care for the output afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments you should separata your **data** from its **represenation**. Your data is just a number, the representation is a nice sweety symbol, which you just print multiple times.

Then you can decrement the number of lives and just render the symbols afterwards:

```
var lives = int;
// something that makes your lives decrease
lives--;
for(int i = 0; i < lives; i++) // print the symbol multiple times
    Console.Write("<3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=net-6.0), as provided by the framework itself.

```
Array.Resize(lives, lives.Length-1)
if(lives.Length <= 0){
   Console.WriteLine("You're dead");
}
```

Or use List:

```
var lives = new List<string>() {"<3", "<3", "<3"};
lives.RemoveAt(lives.Count-1);
```